# mpeg file cannot be replayed

Tags: audio, video, vlc-media-player, windows-media-player

I have problems replaying some `mpeg` file with SMPlayer. Below is the log.
The other UMP just quickly counts the time but nothing can be heared.

Some other WMP opens a dialog with error.
So nowhere I can replay the file. Can this be fixed ?

[image]

```
[18:59:45:467] global_init
[18:59:45:467] global_init: config file: 'C:/Users/hynek0/.smplayer/smplayer.ini'
[18:59:45:467] Preferences::load
[18:59:45:468] AssStyles::load
[18:59:45:468] Preferences::load: config_version: 5, CURRENT_CONFIG_VERSION: 5
[18:59:45:469] Translator::loadCatalog: can't load qt_cs_CZ from C:/Program Files/SMPlayer/translations
[18:59:45:469] Translator::loadCatalog: successfully loaded qtbase_cs_CZ from C:/Program Files/SMPlayer/translations
[18:59:45:469] Translator::loadCatalog: successfully loaded smplayer_cs_CZ from C:/Program Files/SMPlayer/translations
[18:59:45:469] Tohle je SMPlayer v. 21.1.0 (revize 9475) (64-bit) běžící na systému Windows (Windows 8.1/Server 2012 R2)
[18:59:45:469] Compiled with Qt v. 5.6.0, using 5.6.0
[18:59:45:469]  * application path: "C:/Program Files/SMPlayer"
[18:59:45:469]  * data path: "C:/Program Files/SMPlayer"
[18:59:45:469]  * translation path: "C:/Program Files/SMPlayer/translations"
[18:59:45:469]  * doc path: "C:/Program Files/SMPlayer/docs"
[18:59:45:469]  * themes path: "C:/Program Files/SMPlayer/themes"
[18:59:45:469]  * shortcuts path: "C:/Program Files/SMPlayer/shortcuts"
[18:59:45:470]  * config path: "C:/Users/hynek0/.smplayer"
[18:59:45:470]  * ini path: "C:/Users/hynek0/.smplayer"
[18:59:45:470]  * file for subtitles' styles: "C:/Users/hynek0/.smplayer/styles.ass"
[18:59:45:470]  * current path: "C:/Program Files/SMPlayer"
[18:59:45:470] main: hdpi_config_path: "C:/Users/hynek0/.smplayer"
[18:59:45:470] SMPlayer::processArgs: arguments: 2
[18:59:45:470] SMPlayer::processArgs: 0 = C:\Program Files\SMPlayer\smplayer.exe
[18:59:45:470] SMPlayer::processArgs: 1 = C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\FU\J18.mp4
[18:59:45:470] SMPlayer::processArgs: files_to_play: count: 1
[18:59:45:470] SMPlayer::processArgs: files_to_play[0]: 'C:/Users/hynek0/Desktop/FU/J18.mp4'
[18:59:45:471] SMPlayer::gui: changed working directory to app path
[18:59:45:471] SMPlayer::gui: current directory: C:/Program Files/SMPlayer
[18:59:45:471] Screen::setAutoHideCursor: 0
[18:59:45:472] Screen::setAutoHideCursor: 0
[18:59:45:480] Images::setTheme: "H2O" is an internal theme
[18:59:45:480] Images::setThemesPath: ""
[18:59:45:484] MediaSettings::reset
[18:59:45:484] Core::changeFileSettingsMethod: hash
[18:59:45:484] PlayerID::Player: player_bin: "mpv/mpv.exe" filename: "mpv.exe"
[18:59:45:484] PlayerProcess::createPlayerProcess: creating MPVProcess
[18:59:45:485] MPVProcess::initializeOptionVars
[18:59:45:485] MPVProcess::MPVProcess: socket_name: "C:/Users/hynek0/AppData/Local/Temp/smplayer-mpv-188c"
[18:59:45:485] MediaSettings::reset
[18:59:45:485] Preferences::monitor_aspect_double
[18:59:45:485]  warning: monitor_aspect couldn't be parsed!
[18:59:45:485]  monitor_aspect set to 0
[18:59:45:485] WinScreenSaver::retrieveState
[18:59:45:485] WinScreenSaver::retrieveState: lowpower: 0, poweroff: 0, screensaver: 240
[18:59:45:509] Playlist::setModified: 0
[18:59:45:509] Playlist::updateWindowTitle: "Nepojmenovaný playlist"
[18:59:45:518] Recents::addItem: 'http://smplayer.info/sample.m3u8'
[18:59:45:518] Playlist::setConfigPath: "C:/Users/hynek0/.smplayer"
[18:59:45:518] Playlist::setConfigPath: ini file: "C:/Users/hynek0/.smplayer/playlist.ini"
[18:59:45:520] Playlist::loadSettings
[18:59:45:520] Helper::qtVersion: 5600
[18:59:45:521] Playlist::updateWindowTitle: "Nepojmenovaný playlist"
[18:59:45:521] Playlist::setModified: 0
[18:59:45:521] Playlist::updateWindowTitle: "Nepojmenovaný playlist"
[18:59:45:527] BaseGui::BaseGui: default_style: "windowsvista"
[18:59:45:530] Favorites::load
[18:59:45:530] Favorites::load
[18:59:45:531] Favorites::load
[18:59:45:533] BaseGui::initializeMenus
[18:59:45:533] BaseGui::updateBookmarks
[18:59:45:548] BaseGui::initializeMenus
[18:59:45:548] BaseGui::updateBookmarks
[18:59:45:548] BaseGui::updateRecents
[18:59:45:548] BaseGui::updateWidgets
[18:59:45:548] Core::changeUseCustomSubStyle: 1
[18:59:45:548] Core::changeSubVisilibity: 1
[18:59:45:548] Core::displayMessage
[18:59:45:548] PlayerID::Player: player_bin: "mpv/mpv.exe" filename: "mpv.exe"
[18:59:45:548] BaseGui::setupNetworkProxy
[18:59:45:548] BaseGui::setupNetworkProxy: no proxy
[18:59:45:548] BaseGui::setStayOnTop: 0
[18:59:45:548] BaseGui::setStayOnTop: nothing to do
[18:59:45:548] BaseGui::updateWidgets
[18:59:45:548] PlayerID::Player: player_bin: "mpv/mpv.exe" filename: "mpv.exe"
[18:59:45:548] BaseGui::updateRecents
[18:59:45:549] UpdateChecker::UpdateChecker: enabled: true
[18:59:45:549] UpdateChecker::UpdateChecker: days_to_check: 7
[18:59:45:549] UpdateChecker::UpdateChecker: days since last check: 0
[18:59:45:550] BaseGuiPlus::updateSendToScreen
[18:59:45:550] BaseGuiPlus::updateSendAudioMenu
[18:59:45:550] PlayerID::Player: player_bin: "mpv/mpv.exe" filename: "mpv.exe"
[18:59:45:550] PlayerID::Player: player_bin: "mpv/mpv.exe" filename: "mpv.exe"
[18:59:45:550] DeviceInfo::mpvAudioDevices
[18:59:45:678] DeviceInfo::mpvAudioDevices: "List of detected audio devices:"
[18:59:45:678] DeviceInfo::mpvAudioDevices: "'auto' (Autoselect device)"
[18:59:45:678] DeviceInfo::mpvAudioDevices: "'wasapi/{27af5561-cc4e-4384-aa9e-22c4047649b2}' (Reproduktory (Realtek High Definition Audio))"
[18:59:45:678] DeviceInfo::mpvAudioDevices: device: "{27af5561-cc4e-4384-aa9e-22c4047649b2}" name: "Reproduktory (Realtek High Definition Audio)"
[18:59:45:678] DeviceInfo::mpvAudioDevices: "'openal' (Default (openal))"
[18:59:45:678] DeviceInfo::mpvAudioDevices: "'sdl' (Default (sdl))"
[18:59:45:678] GlobalShortcuts::GlobalShortcuts
[18:59:45:678] GlobalShortcuts::setEnabled: false
[18:59:45:679] Chromecast::loadSettings
[18:59:45:681] BaseGui::initializeMenus
[18:59:45:681] BaseGui::updateBookmarks
[18:59:45:681] BaseGui::updateRecents
[18:59:45:681] BaseGuiPlus::updateWidgets
[18:59:45:681] BaseGui::updateWidgets
[18:59:45:681] PlayerID::Player: player_bin: "mpv/mpv.exe" filename: "mpv.exe"
[18:59:45:682] BaseGuiPlus::loadConfig
[18:59:45:682] DefaultGui::createStatusBar
[18:59:45:683] StateWidget::StateWidget: supported formats for QMovie: ("gif")
[18:59:45:683] DefaultGui::createActions
[18:59:45:683] DefaultGui::createControlWidget
[18:59:45:683] DefaultGui::createControlWidgetMini
[18:59:45:683] AutohideWidget::installFilter: child name: "mplayerlayer"
[18:59:45:683] AutohideWidget::installFilter: child name: "mplayerwindowlogo"
[18:59:45:683] AutohideWidget::installFilter: child name: ""
[18:59:45:683] DefaultGui::adjustFloatingControlSize
[18:59:45:684] DefaultGui::populateMainMenu
[18:59:45:684] BaseGuiPlus::populateMainMenu
[18:59:45:684] BaseGui::populateMainMenu
[18:59:45:684] BaseGuiPlus::initializeSystrayMenu
[18:59:45:685] BaseGui::initializeMenus
[18:59:45:686] BaseGui::updateBookmarks
[18:59:45:686] BaseGui::updateRecents
[18:59:45:686] DefaultGui::updateWidgets
[18:59:45:686] BaseGuiPlus::updateWidgets
[18:59:45:686] BaseGui::updateWidgets
[18:59:45:686] PlayerID::Player: player_bin: "mpv/mpv.exe" filename: "mpv.exe"
[18:59:45:686] PlayerID::Player: player_bin: "mpv/mpv.exe" filename: "mpv.exe"
[18:59:45:686] PlayerID::Player: player_bin: "mpv/mpv.exe" filename: "mpv.exe"
[18:59:45:686] DefaultGui::loadConfig
[18:59:45:687] DesktopInfo::isInsideScreen: geometry of screen: QRect(0,0 1600x1200)
[18:59:45:687] DesktopInfo::isInsideScreen: center point of window: QPoint(573,150)
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: 'toolbar1'
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action open_file
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action open_url
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action favorites_menu
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action separator
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: adding separator
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action screenshot
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action separator
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: adding separator
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action show_file_properties
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action show_playlist
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action show_tube_browser
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action separator
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: adding separator
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action show_preferences
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action separator
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: adding separator
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action play_prev
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action play_next
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action separator
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: adding separator
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action audiotrack_menu
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action subtitlestrack_menu
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: 'controlwidget'
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action play_or_pause
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action stop
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action separator
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: adding separator
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action rewindbutton_action
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action timeslider_action
[18:59:45:687] TimeSlider::setDragDelay: 100
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action forwardbutton_action
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action separator
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: adding separator
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action fullscreen
[18:59:45:687] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action mute
[18:59:45:688] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action volumeslider_action
[18:59:45:688] ToolbarEditor::load: 'controlwidget_mini'
[18:59:45:688] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action play_or_pause
[18:59:45:688] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action stop
[18:59:45:688] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action separator
[18:59:45:688] ToolbarEditor::load: adding separator
[18:59:45:688] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action rewind1
[18:59:45:688] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action timeslider_action
[18:59:45:688] TimeSlider::setDragDelay: 100
[18:59:45:688] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action forward1
[18:59:45:688] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action separator
[18:59:45:688] ToolbarEditor::load: adding separator
[18:59:45:688] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action mute
[18:59:45:688] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action volumeslider_action
[18:59:45:688] ToolbarEditor::load: 'floating_control'
[18:59:45:688] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action play_or_pause
[18:59:45:688] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action stop
[18:59:45:688] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action separator
[18:59:45:688] ToolbarEditor::load: adding separator
[18:59:45:688] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action rewind1
[18:59:45:688] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action current_timelabel_action
[18:59:45:688] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action timeslider_action
[18:59:45:688] TimeSlider::setDragDelay: 100
[18:59:45:688] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action total_timelabel_action
[18:59:45:688] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action forward1
[18:59:45:688] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action separator
[18:59:45:688] ToolbarEditor::load: adding separator
[18:59:45:689] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action fullscreen
[18:59:45:689] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action mute
[18:59:45:689] ToolbarEditor::load: loading action volumeslider_action
[18:59:45:690] Helper::qtVersion: 5600
[18:59:45:691] DefaultGui::updateWidgets
[18:59:45:691] BaseGuiPlus::updateWidgets
[18:59:45:691] BaseGui::updateWidgets
[18:59:45:691] PlayerID::Player: player_bin: "mpv/mpv.exe" filename: "mpv.exe"
[18:59:45:691] PlayerID::Player: player_bin: "mpv/mpv.exe" filename: "mpv.exe"
[18:59:45:691] PlayerID::Player: player_bin: "mpv/mpv.exe" filename: "mpv.exe"
[18:59:45:691] BaseGui::applyStyles
[18:59:45:691] BaseGui::applyStyles: stylesheet: "H2O"
[18:59:45:691] BaseGui::changeStyleSheet: "H2O"
[18:59:45:691] BaseGui::loadQss: :/default-theme/style.qss
[18:59:45:691] Images::setTheme: "H2O" is an internal theme
[18:59:45:691] Images::setThemesPath: ""
[18:59:45:691] BaseGui::changeStyleSheet: ":/H2O/style.qss"
[18:59:45:691] BaseGui::loadQss: :/H2O/style.qss
[18:59:45:692] Images::setTheme: "H2O" is an internal theme
[18:59:45:692] Images::setThemesPath: ""
[18:59:45:706] BaseGui::applyStyles: style: "Fusion"
[18:59:45:776] BaseGui::showEvent
[18:59:45:799] BaseGui::setInitialSecond: 0
[18:59:45:799] BaseGui::openFiles
[18:59:45:799] Playlist::setModified: 0
[18:59:45:799] Playlist::updateWindowTitle: "Nepojmenovaný playlist"
[18:59:45:799] Playlist::addFiles
[18:59:45:799] Playlist::addFiles: latest_dir: "C:/Users/hynek0/Desktop/FU"
[18:59:45:799] BaseGui::open: 'C:/Users/hynek0/Desktop/FU/J18.mp4'
[18:59:45:799] Core::open: 'C:/Users/hynek0/Desktop/FU/J18.mp4'
[18:59:45:799] Core::open: * identified as local file
[18:59:45:799] Core::openFile: 'C:/Users/hynek0/Desktop/FU/J18.mp4'
[18:59:45:799] Core::playNewFile: 'C:/Users/hynek0/Desktop/FU/J18.mp4'
[18:59:45:799] Core::saveMediaInfo
[18:59:45:799] MediaSettings::reset
[18:59:45:799] FileSettingsHash::existSettingsFor: "C:/Users/hynek0/Desktop/FU/J18.mp4"
[18:59:45:800] FileSettingsHash::existSettingsFor: config_file: "C:/Users/hynek0/.smplayer/file_settings/f/f79de0176f5ed80b.ini"
[18:59:45:800] Core::playNewFile: we have settings for this file
[18:59:45:800] Core::restoreSettingsForMedia: "C:/Users/hynek0/Desktop/FU/J18.mp4" type: 0
[18:59:45:800] FileSettings::loadSettingsFor: "C:/Users/hynek0/Desktop/FU/J18.mp4" type: 0
[18:59:45:800] FileSettingsHash::loadSettingsFor: config_file: "C:/Users/hynek0/.smplayer/file_settings/f/f79de0176f5ed80b.ini"
[18:59:45:800] MediaSettings::reset
[18:59:45:800] MediaSettings::load
[18:59:45:800] MediaSettings::load: demuxer_section: demuxer_unknown
[18:59:45:800] MediaSettings::load: list of video tracks:
[18:59:45:800] MediaSettings::load: list of audio tracks:
[18:59:45:800] MediaSettings::load: list of subtitle tracks:
[18:59:45:800] Core::restoreSettingsForMedia: media settings read
[18:59:45:800] Core::playNewFile: volume: 40, old_volume: 40
[18:59:45:800] Core::initPlaying
[18:59:45:801] MplayerWindow::setLogoVisible: false
[18:59:45:801] Core::startMplayer: file: "C:/Users/hynek0/Desktop/FU/J18.mp4" seek: 0
[18:59:45:801] RetrieveYoutubeUrl::close
[18:59:45:801] Core::startMplayer: checking if stream is a playlist
[18:59:45:801] Core::startMplayer: url path: '/Users/hynek0/Desktop/FU/J18.mp4'
[18:59:45:801] Core::startMplayer: url_is_playlist: 0
[18:59:45:801] InfoReader::setPlayerBin: mplayerbin: "C:/Program Files/SMPlayer/mpv/mpv.exe"
[18:59:45:801] InfoReader::getInfo: sname: "C__Program Files_SMPlayer_mpv_mpv_exe_60804627"
[18:59:45:803] InfoReader::getInfo: loaded info from "C:/Users/hynek0/.smplayer/player_info.ini"
[18:59:45:807] Core::startMplayer: edl file: ''
[18:59:45:807] Core::startMplayer: extra_params: ()
[18:59:45:807] MplayerLayer::playingStarted
[18:59:45:807] Screen::playingStarted
[18:59:45:807] Screen::setAutoHideCursor: 1
[18:59:45:807] Screen::playingStarted
[18:59:45:807] Screen::setAutoHideCursor: 1
[18:59:45:807] Core::disableScreensaver
[18:59:45:807] Core::startMplayer: command: 'C:/Program Files/SMPlayer/mpv/mpv.exe --no-config --no-quiet --terminal --no-msg-color --input-ipc-server=C:/Users/hynek0/AppData/Local/Temp/smplayer-mpv-188c --msg-level=ffmpeg/demuxer=error --no-fs --hwdec=no --sub-auto=fuzzy --vo=direct3d, --priority=normal --no-input-default-bindings --input-vo-keyboard=no --no-input-cursor --cursor-autohide=no --no-keepaspect --wid=4065030 --monitorpixelaspect=1 --osd-level=1 --osd-scale=1 --osd-bar-align-y=0.6 --sub-ass --embeddedfonts --sub-ass-line-spacing=0 --sub-scale=1 --sub-font=Arial --sub-color=#ffffffff --sub-shadow-color=#ff000000 --sub-border-color=#ff000000 --sub-border-size=0.75 --sub-shadow-offset=2.5 --sub-font-size=50 --sub-bold=no --sub-italic=no --sub-margin-y=8 --sub-margin-x=20 --sub-codepage=ISO-8859-1 --sub-pos=100 --volume=99 --cache=auto --screenshot-template=cap_%F_%p_%02n --screenshot-format=jpg --screenshot-directory=C:\Users\hynek0\Pictures\smplayer_screenshots --audio-pitch-correction=yes --af-add=@aeq:lavfi=[firequalizer=gain='cubic_interpolate(f)':zero_phase=on:wfunc=tukey:delay=0.027:gain_entry='entry(0,0);entry(62.5,0);entry(125,0);entry(250,0);entry(500,0);entry(1000,0);entry(2000,0);entry(4000,0);entry(8000,0);entry(16000,0)'] --volume-max=100 --term-playing-msg=MPV_VERSION=${=mpv-version:}
INFO_VIDEO_WIDTH=${=width}
INFO_VIDEO_HEIGHT=${=height}
INFO_VIDEO_ASPECT=${=video-params/aspect}
INFO_VIDEO_FPS=${=container-fps:${=fps}}
INFO_VIDEO_FORMAT=${=video-format}
INFO_VIDEO_CODEC=${=video-codec}
INFO_AUDIO_FORMAT=${=audio-codec-name}
INFO_AUDIO_CODEC=${=audio-codec}
INFO_AUDIO_RATE=${=audio-params/samplerate}
INFO_AUDIO_NCH=${=audio-params/channel-count}
INFO_LENGTH=${=duration:${=length}}
INFO_DEMUXER=${=current-demuxer:${=demuxer}}
INFO_SEEKABLE=${=seekable}
INFO_TITLES=${=disc-titles}
INFO_CHAPTERS=${=chapters}
INFO_TRACKS_COUNT=${=track-list/count}
METADATA_TITLE=${metadata/by-key/title:}
METADATA_ARTIST=${metadata/by-key/artist:}
METADATA_ALBUM=${metadata/by-key/album:}
METADATA_GENRE=${metadata/by-key/genre:}
METADATA_DATE=${metadata/by-key/date:}
METADATA_TRACK=${metadata/by-key/track:}
METADATA_COPYRIGHT=${metadata/by-key/copyright:}
INFO_MEDIA_TITLE=${=media-title:}
INFO_STREAM_PATH=${stream-path}
 --term-status-msg=STATUS: ${=time-pos} / ${=duration:${=length:0}} P: ${=pause} B: ${=paused-for-cache} I: ${=core-idle} VB: ${=video-bitrate:0} AB: ${=audio-bitrate:0} C:/Users/hynek0/Desktop/FU/J18.mp4'
[18:59:45:817] BaseGui::loadActions
[18:59:45:817] ActionsEditor::loadFromConfig
[18:59:45:850] BaseGui::initializeMenus
[18:59:45:850] BaseGui::updateBookmarks
[18:59:45:850] BaseGui::updateRecents
[18:59:45:850] DefaultGui::updateWidgets
[18:59:45:850] BaseGuiPlus::updateWidgets
[18:59:45:850] BaseGui::updateWidgets
[18:59:45:850] PlayerID::Player: player_bin: "mpv/mpv.exe" filename: "mpv.exe"
[18:59:45:850] PlayerID::Player: player_bin: "mpv/mpv.exe" filename: "mpv.exe"
[18:59:45:850] PlayerID::Player: player_bin: "mpv/mpv.exe" filename: "mpv.exe"
[18:59:45:879] BaseGuiPlus::updateShortcutsContext
[18:59:46:550] BaseGui::checkReminder
[18:59:47:124] MPVProcess::parseLine: " (+) Audio --aid=1 (*) (aac 2ch 22050Hz)"
[18:59:47:124] MPVProcess::parseLine: audio id: 1 lang: "" name: ""
[18:59:47:124] MPVProcess::updateAudioTrack: ID: 1
[18:59:47:128] MPVProcess::parseLine: "[ffmpeg/demuxer] mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2: Incorrect number of samples in encryption info"
[18:59:47:128] MPVProcess::parseLine: "[lavf] error reading packet: Invalid data found when processing input."
[18:59:47:128] MPVProcess::parseLine: "[ffmpeg/demuxer] mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2: Incorrect number of samples in encryption info"
[18:59:47:129] MPVProcess::parseLine: "[lavf] error reading packet: Invalid data found when processing input."
[18:59:47:130] MPVProcess::parseLine: "[ffmpeg/demuxer] mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2: Incorrect number of samples in encryption info"
[18:59:47:130] MPVProcess::parseLine: "[lavf] error reading packet: Invalid data found when processing input."
[18:59:47:130] MPVProcess::parseLine: "MPV_VERSION=mpv 0.32.0"
[18:59:47:130] MPVProcess::parseLine: mpv version: "0.32.0"
[18:59:47:131] MplayerVersion::mplayerVersion: mpv version found: "0.32.0"
[18:59:47:131] MplayerVersion::mplayerVersion: mplayer_svn: 33472
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::parseLine: "INFO_VIDEO_WIDTH="
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::parseLine: md.video_width set to 0
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::parseLine: "INFO_VIDEO_HEIGHT="
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::parseLine: md.video_height set to 0
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::parseLine: "INFO_VIDEO_ASPECT="
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::parseLine: md.video_aspect set to nan
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::parseLine: "INFO_VIDEO_FPS=0.000000"
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::parseLine: "INFO_VIDEO_FORMAT="
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::parseLine: "INFO_VIDEO_CODEC="
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::parseLine: "INFO_AUDIO_FORMAT=aac"
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::parseLine: "INFO_AUDIO_CODEC=aac (AAC (Advanced Audio Coding))"
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::parseLine: md.audio_codec: "aac"
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::parseLine: "INFO_AUDIO_RATE="
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::parseLine: "INFO_AUDIO_NCH="
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::parseLine: "INFO_LENGTH=19032.932426"
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::parseLine: md.duration set to 19032.9
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::parseLine: "INFO_DEMUXER=lavf"
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::parseLine: "INFO_SEEKABLE=yes"
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::parseLine: "INFO_TITLES="
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::parseLine: "INFO_CHAPTERS=0"
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::parseLine: "INFO_TRACKS_COUNT=1"
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::sendCommand: "print_text \"INFO_TRACK_0: ${track-list/0/type} ${track-list/0/id} '${track-list/0/lang:}' '${track-list/0/title:}' ${track-list/0/selected}\""
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::sendCommand: state: QLocalSocket::UnconnectedState
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::sendCommand: error: "Neznámá chyba"
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::sendCommand: state: QLocalSocket::ConnectedState
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::parseLine: "METADATA_TITLE="
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::parseLine: "METADATA_ARTIST="
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::parseLine: "METADATA_ALBUM="
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::parseLine: "METADATA_GENRE="
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::parseLine: "METADATA_DATE="
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::parseLine: "METADATA_TRACK="
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::parseLine: "METADATA_COPYRIGHT="
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::parseLine: "INFO_MEDIA_TITLE=J18.mp4"
[18:59:47:131] MPVProcess::parseLine: "INFO_STREAM_PATH=C:/Users/hynek0/Desktop/FU/J18.mp4"
[18:59:47:132] MPVProcess::parseLine: "INFO_TRACK_0: (error) (error) '' '' (error)"
[18:59:47:267] MPVProcess::parseLine: "Exiting... (Errors when loading file)"
[18:59:47:330] MyProcess::procFinished
[18:59:47:330] MyProcess::procFinished: Bytes available:  0
[18:59:47:330] MPVProcess::processFinished: exitCode: 2, status: 0
[18:59:47:330] MplayerLayer::playingStopped
[18:59:47:330] Screen::playingStopped
[18:59:47:330] Screen::setAutoHideCursor: 0
[18:59:47:330] Screen::playingStopped
[18:59:47:330] Screen::setAutoHideCursor: 0
[18:59:47:330] Core::enableScreensaver
[18:59:47:330] Core::processFinished
[18:59:47:330] Core::processFinished: we_are_restarting: 0
[18:59:47:330] Core::processFinished: play has finished!
[18:59:47:330] Core::processFinished: exit_code: 2
[18:59:47:330] BaseGui::displayState: "Stopped"
[18:59:47:333] DefaultGui::togglePlayAction
[18:59:47:333] BaseGui::togglePlayAction
[18:59:47:334] StateWidget::watchState: 0
[18:59:47:334] BaseGui::showExitCodeFromMplayer: 2
[18:59:47:334] BaseGui::showExitCodeFromMplayer: not displaying error dialog
[18:59:47:345] Playlist::playerFinishedWithError: 2
[18:59:47:345] BaseGui::checkStayOnTop
[18:59:58:140] BaseGui::showLog
```

Comment: Just a comment, but if you are having problems with the same file and multiple players, it sounds plausible to me that the file is damaged somehow.

Comment: @Anaksunaman I have tried many `.mp4` files. Previously they worked but not now.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried many .mp4 files. Previously they worked but not now.

Beyond damaged files, the other issue that springs to mind is that this may be some sort of [codec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codec) issue.

That is, the files you're are attempting to play back were put together in such a way that despite having `.mp4` as a [container format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_format_(computing)) or extension, the actual video and audio streams are in formats that the media players you're having trouble with don't understand.

If this is the case, then the "fix" could be one (or more) of the following:

- Get the proper codec(s). This can include:

  - Updates to the players themselves. Or, alternatively, downgrading if a codec is very old and not included with a player any longer.
  - Installing separate codec packs. This could be individual installation programs e.g. designed for the player, the OS in general, or projects like the [Combined Community Codec Pack](http://www.cccp-project.net/).
- Re-encode the video(s) yourself with GUI media editing tools or a command line tool such as [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) (currently, Windows builds of FFmpeg are available from [gyan.dev](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/) and, alternately, this GitHub release repository).
- Generally ensure the files have the correct extension (again with tools such as e.g. FFmpeg).

---

*As a side comment, I have never had any luck with SMPlayer. I might humbly suggest trying another player (beyond UMP/WMP). Regarding players I would recommend investigating:*

- *The Windows port of [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/) (assuming you want a good GUI player).*
- *A minimalist [Windows port of MPV](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mpv-player-windows/files/) (FYI, [MPV](https://mpv.io/) is what SMPlayer is built around). You can use it in conjunction with the Windows executable build of [youtube-dl](https://youtube-dl.org/) to play a lot of media directly through URLs.*
- *[Baka Player](https://u8sand.github.io/Baka-MPlayer/installation/). It's old and out of date, but comes closest to something like SMPlayer or UMP and is built around libmpv.*

---